# react-navigation withNavigation returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-navigation

In my react-native app, I have a component for my header with back button. It works except for when I click the back button and it gives me this error: **undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation)**

So I followed the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html) and tried using `withNavigation`. But I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

const HeaderWithBackBtn = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {/* Back button */}
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={{width: 100}} 
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                <Text style={styles.backBtn}>Back</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Text style={styles.text}> {props.screen} </Text>

            {/* Placeholder button */}
            <Text style={{width: 100}}></Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
});

export default withNavigation(HeaderWithBackBtn);
```

Comment: how did you pass your props to your HeaderWithBackBtn component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component you're wrapping is a functional component, so you need to access your props as `props.foo` rather than as `this.props.foo`.

```
onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}>
```

should work fine.